# Order of variable declaration in data segment causes different outputs

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I use TASM.

I use [this](ftp://cse.shirazu.ac.ir:5001/Tempbuffer/mk/IO.H) IO.h file for input and output from/to the console. And also for `itoa` and `atoi`.

My program is : (The purpose is to simply copy to `20h` to 2 memory locations and output both.)

```
include io.h

data segment
    msg2 db 13, 10, "here it is", 13, 10, 0
    tmp dw ?, 0
    num dw ?, 0
    tmp2 dw ?, 0
data ends
code segment
    assume cs:code, ds:data
    start:
        ;load segments
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax

    ;store 20h
    mov ax, 20h
    ;copy to both num and tmp2
    mov num, ax
    mov tmp2, ax

    ;output
    output msg2
            ; (itoa puts the output-able into destination, "tmp" here)
    itoa tmp, tmp2
    output tmp

    ;output
    output msg2
    itoa tmp, num
    output tmp
    ;return control
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
code ends
    end start
```

The output I get is :

```
here it is
32
here it is
12851
```

However when I make a small change in order of variable definition ( I swap tmp2 and num ):

```
data segment
    msg2 db 13, 10, "here it is", 13, 10, 0
    tmp dw ?, 0
    tmp2 dw ?, 0
    num dw ?, 0
data ends
```

The output is :

```
here it is
32
here it is
32
```

Can someone explain why this happens?
The 2nd output is what I expected in both cases.

p.s : Also, why do we have to use the `start` label? I find it extremely strange that it extends **out of** the code segment. It doesn't work correctly without that label.

Comment: `end start` tells the assembler and linker two things: all assembly source code ends here and `start` is where execution should start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `io.h` you linked only contains a macro that calls the `itoa_proc` in a library, as such we don't know how that procedure works. It probably uses some extra space, so even through the result (`32`) fits into 2 bytes, it may be overwriting following memory locations hence destroying your value. Note that `12851` is `0x3233` which in memory looks like `0x33`, `0x32` which is just the ascii representation of `32`. Just guessing here, but `itoa` may be producing right-justified output first, then moving it to the left.

Read the documentation or the source code, if available, or just reserve more space for the output string. I assume for 16 bit numbers 7 bytes should be enough: 1 for possible sign, 5 for the digits, 1 for the terminating zero.